# CUDA out of memory error when reloading Pytorch model

Tags: memory, pytorch, gpu, out-of-memory

Common pytorch error here, but I'm seeing it under a unique circumstance: when reloading a model, I get a `CUDA: Out of Memory` error, even though I haven't yet placed the model on the GPU.

```py
model = model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_file_path))
optimizer = optimizer.load_state_dict(torch.load(optimizer_file_path))
# Error happens here ^, before I send the model to the device.
model = model.to(device_id)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that I was trying to load to a new GPU (`cuda:2`) but originally saved the model and optimizer from a different GPU (`cuda:0`). So even though I didn't explicitly tell it to reload to the previous GPU, the default behavior is to reload to the original GPU (which happened to be occupied).

Adding `map_location=device_id` to each `torch.load` call fixed the problem:

```py
model.to(device_id)
model = model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_file_path, map_location=device_id))
optimizer = optimizer.load_state_dict(torch.load(optimizer_file_path, map_location=device_id))
```